# Add GeoJson Source in Mapbox GL JS for Pie Chart creation

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I'm very new to MapBox and JavaScript/html, I'm building a Washington DC crime map with a large 10 year data set that is on my local system. The file is to large(roughly 45mb) to host on MapBox (5mb file limit). Ive tried Github pages and cant get that to work either. I need my java script to access the dataset and create pie charts using a few attributes withing the set.

I've tried alot of different ways to access the data, host it on github pages then passing the url to the add source mapbox function. I never was able to figured out the right way to do that. Ive tried to access the file using the path to it locally but I also cant figure out the right way to do that. Additionally I tried to use a sub set of the data, just ward 3 data, upload that to mapbox datasets and try accessing it that way and i get a blocked by cors policy error.

this is my most recent attempt trying to access the file I uploaded to mapbox. this returns the following error.I want to add a source and then make a cluster for each policing Shift attribute type. Not sure if this would be how to do the clusting correctly but at the moment I cant load the data correctly yet so I need to overcome that hurdle first.

> ERROR Access to fetch at
>   'https://studio.mapbox.com/datasets/benpdoiron/cjuo3a0wha6knu9q7t9ze5gvc/'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

CODE SNIPPET

```
var url="https://studio.mapbox.com/datasets/benpdoiron/cjuo3a0wha6knu9q7t9ze5gvc/";

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('Pie_Chart1', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: url,
        cluster: true,
        clusterProperties: { 
        day: ["+", ["get", 'DAY']],
        evening: ["+", ["get", 'EVENING']],
        midnight: ["+", ["get", 'MIDNIGHT']]

        }
```

The expected outcome is that the data loads and I can create functions and layers using its attributes and information. Ideally I think hosting the whole dataset, roughly 45mb, on github pages and accessing it there would be the way to go but I cant seem to figure out how to pass the file mapbox add source properly

Comment: Ive been Following this mapbox documentations and attempting to mold it to my dataset. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster-html/

Comment: This troubleshooting guide should help you with your CORS error: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/cors-errors/